# How to give the database server higher priority on network connection

Tags: networking, network-shares, priority

I have a sybase database engine installed on a windows server 2008, there are shares also and active directory on the server, when the shares are accessed from many users at the same time the application depending on the sybase database server become so slow and may hang up on save and requests.

what i see is that shared files transfer is given high priority it reaches from 9.5 to 10.5 MB per second , it takes almost the whole Ethernet channel.

i was wondering if there is any way to give my database engine higher priority????

Answer (score 0):

Server 2008 and Server 2008R2 both support Quality of Service (QOS) which can prioritize traffic based on various characteristics.

A good reference is the TechNet article: [Quality of Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb530836.aspx)

Comment: I wish if the system can be moved to ms sql server the people of company that developed the system are stick to sybase sql anywhere version 6.0